# Android GreenDao update database scheme

Tags: java, android, greendao, greendao3

I have an encrypted database and in this database I have some table. Now I would like to add an extra column to one of my table, but the *onUpgrade()* method never called.

I init my database like this:

```
private void initDatabase(){
    if (MyApp.this.daoSession == null) {
        DatabaseUpgradeHelper helper = new DatabaseUpgradeHelper(this, "myapp-db-enc");
        Database db = helper.getWritableDatabase("XXXXXXX");
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        MyApp.this.daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
}
```

My *DatabaseUpgradeHelper* object based on this example: [Example](https://github.com/PierceZ/greenDAOMigrationExample/blob/master/src/main/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/example/DatabaseUpgradeHelper.java)

My implementation is here:

```
public class DatabaseUpgradeHelper extends DaoMaster.EncryptedOpenHelper {

public DatabaseUpgradeHelper(Context context, String name) {
    super(context, name);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    List<Migration> migrations = getMigrations();

    // Only run migrations past the old version
    for (Migration migration : migrations) {
        if (oldVersion < migration.getVersion()) {
            migration.runMigration(db);
        }
    }
}

private List<Migration> getMigrations() {
    List<Migration> migrations = new ArrayList<>();
    migrations.add(new MigrationV3());
    //migrations.add(new MigrationV3());

    // Sorting just to be safe, in case other people add migrations in the wrong order.
    Comparator<Migration> migrationComparator = new Comparator<Migration>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Migration m1, Migration m2) {
            return m1.getVersion().compareTo(m2.getVersion());
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(migrations, migrationComparator);

    return migrations;
}

private static class MigrationV3 implements Migration {

    @Override
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void runMigration(Database db) {
        // Add new column to user table
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + GlobalSettingsEntityDao.TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN " + GlobalSettingsEntityDao.Properties.FeatureScreenLastSeenVersion.columnName + " INTEGER");
    }
}

private interface Migration {
    Integer getVersion();

    void runMigration(Database db);
}
}
```

I debugged my code but the app never called the *onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)* method. Why?

UPDATE: I use greenDao 3.1.1

UPDATE2:
Here is the exception:

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such column: T.FEATURE_SCREEN_LAST_SEEN_VERSION: , while compiling: SELECT T."_id",T."PINLOCK_PROTECTION",T."PLACES_LAST_SYNC_TIME",T."LAST_SERVER_PREFIX",T."LANGUAGE",T."WELCOME_SCREEN_LAST_SEEN_VERSION",T."LAST_VERSION_CHECK",T."STORE_NETWORK_LOG_DAY",T."IS_FIRST_LOGIN",T."KEEP_LOGGED_IN",T."FEATURE_SCREEN_LAST_SEEN_VERSION" FROM "GLOBAL_SETTINGS_ENTITY" T 
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1762)
                                                            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
                                                            at de.greenrobot.dao.database.EncryptedDatabase.rawQuery(EncryptedDatabase.java:31)
                                                            at de.greenrobot.dao.query.Query.list(Query.java:76)
                                                            at de.greenrobot.dao.query.QueryBuilder.list(QueryBuilder.java:389)
                                                            at myapp.app.database.datasources.SettingsDatabaseHelper.getStoreNetworkLogDay(SettingsDatabaseHelper.java:600)
                                                            at myapp.app.database.DatabaseHelper.deleteOldNetworkLog(DatabaseHelper.java:272)
                                                            at myapp.app.activities.GateActivity$1.run(GateActivity.java:137)
                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: have you debugged your code ? I think you are getting an exception there.

Comment: Yes I got SQLiteException: no such column

Comment: @Umair I updated my question with the exception

Comment: I think you modified your database before so now you have 2 options, either uninstall and then install the app again or you have to write an update script from the old version of the Database to the new version.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I have to uninstall app, install the previous version (old db structure) and install the new new version (new db structure) and at the first run, the onUpgrade() method called. Thank you!

Comment: no problem. :) happy to help you.